# Masonry Jquery layout to wrap around box (like the letter L)

Tags: html, css, css-float, jquery-masonry

I'm building a site with big box (div) floating at the left upper corner of the site, and I want to give the thumbnails float around it (like mirrored letter L).

Using cornerStampSelector, just don't do it, the thumbnails just appears blow the box, the same happens when I try to use the main dive as the first element.

Any ideas?

```
-------------------
floated*          *
 div   *thumbmails*
------ *          *
      goes here   *
                  *
-------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, Just define the html-body as the container.